# 'Windows PHP PDO requires nextRowset while 'Nix does not, how can I fix this?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

On linux and mac we are using the dblib (FreeTDS) drivers. On Windows we are using Microsofts SQLSRV drivers. We are stuck with a mixed environment like this for a little bit, it sucks but it is what it is.

If we have a query that will insert into a @variable table or a #temp table then use those results to join in on something else it causes the issue we have.

A pseudo query to demonstrate:

```
CREATE TABLE #someTempTable(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
)
INSERT INTO #someTempTable
SELECT someID FROM someRealTable
WHERE someColumn = someValue;


SELECT * FROM #someTempTable
INNER JOIN someOtherTable
      ON someOtherTable.id = #someTempTable.id

DROP #someTempTable
```

On Windows we have to call $statement->nextRowset() before we can get the results otherwise it's empty

On 'Nix the results are available without calling this.

What is really annoying is that there is no way in PDO to get the number of Rowsets or even see if there is another after the "current" one.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns more than one rowset, you have to call `nextRowset()` in order to get access to the next one. No exceptions.

If in some environment you don't have to call it, then it's a bug and you have to report it, providing a minimal reproduceable example. Your current sketch does not confirm with this requirement as it cannot be run by anyone, due to torn SQL and absence of PDO code.

So, first of all start from creating one. Most likely in the process you will find an error in your own code and thus solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to call platform-specific code in PHP you can check the `PHP_OS` constant:

```
if ('WIN' === strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3))){
    // Do Windows-specific stuff here
}else{
    // Do non-Windows stuff here
}
```

The `PHP_OS` constant and other pre-defined constants can be found [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).